# ceiling fan w/remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

My porch lights are wired with 12-2. I want to control the ceiling fan, i.e. light and fan independent of other porch lights. I believe this requires running a 12-3, which I wont do. Having said that can I  still install/attach a wireless remote to the ceiling fan, granted the other lights will be left on but have ability to turn ceiling fan light on/off and or control fan with the remote realizing the other porch lights will remain on?
Or can I install a dimer switch to dim the other porch lights and control ceiling fan light /fan with remote?

Comment: I believe OP has existing lights that aren't part of the ceiling fan fixture.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can purchase a remote control module that will allow you to independently control the fan and the light. Most modules only require a hot, neutral, and ground wire to operate.

Here's a wiring diagram from a [random fan remote](http://www.nutone.com/products/product/e18fbfd8-3d99-4537-aeba-23f1c3c30c84), [installation guide (PDF)](http://www.nutone.com/common/productDigitalAssethandler.ashx?id=d02e3c6a-d490-4222-ae41-03ebab4b0b34).

> [image: Wiring diagram]

The receiver gets power from the house wiring, then determines which leads to energized based on the buttons pressed on the remote.